# Can someone explain these lines of Laravel code?

Tags: php, laravel

I am completely new to Laravel and I have been given a project I need to edit. So I have been tracing through the project trying to understand what it is doing. I have read a lot of the docs and I have run across something I don't fully understand.

Can someone help explain these lines of code:

```html
$account = Account::find($account_id);
$settings = $account->accountSettings;
```

So specifically the: `Account::find($account_id);` and the `$account->accountSettings;`

Obviously, you aren't going to know what the variables contain and stuff, I am not asking for that. I am asking strictly for understanding WHAT is happening specifically.

Answer (score 2):

```
$account = Account::find($account_id);
```

This line means `SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = $account_id` LIMIT 1 in mysql.
This will return the whole row in a single object. Another example would be:

```
$account = Account::where('id', $account_id)->get();
```

This line will means `SELECT * FROM account WHERE id = $account_id` in mysql. This will return all rows with id = account_id in an array of objects.

```
$settings = $account->accountSettings;
```

This line means assigning the value of $account->accountSettings to $settings.
So for example IF:

`$account->accountSettings` has a value of "foo"

`$settings` will have a value of "foo" too

the 'accountSettings' in `$account->accountSettings` could mean a column in the table of 'account', or it is simply a properties of 'account'.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The `Account::find()` format is calling the database. So what is `$account->accountSettings` though? Would that be a file? or like a structure?

Comment: @AustinHunter please see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The first line tells laravel to look into accounts table and get the line where the id is equal to `$account_id` then bind it to an object ($account), and the second line is to get `accountSettings` column value inside `$settings` variable